# Django foreign relations regarding form and multiple file upload

Tags: python, django

i have a Patient model, which can contain many files uploaded by the staff ( test results of all sorts ) , 
what happens is that the form for adding a new patient and uploading files to that patient cannot go through because the file feed is initially empty, but it cannot be empty.. 
here is the code

```
//models.py
class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tests = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    feed = models.ForeignKey('Feed', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
class FeedFile(models.Model):

    files = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.files
class Feed(models.Model):
    name = 'files'
    files=models.ManyToManyField(FeedFile, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
//views.py
class PatientCreate(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    fields = ['name']
//forms.py
class NewPatientForm(ModelForm):
    files = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewPatientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['feed'].required = False
```

as you can see in the last part i have even tried to define that the feed field can be empty, but still when filling out the new patient form  it wont go through ( " this field is required")

Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't you just add `null=True` to `feed`? If you don't want it to be required?

Comment: I've tried that,   sadly it doesn't work